# How Can I upload ASPNETDB Database to Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, aspnetdb

I have uploaded my database backup and it works fine. but since I've created a new user from ASP.NET Configuration I've that it saves the user information in the ASPNETDB.

I already published my database from MVS and open it in M SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to create the backup but I haven't find the ASPNETDB in it.

my question is:

1. doesn't this database just upload it automatically when I upload my database? coz when I publish my website it doesn't appear.
2. if not, How can I upload ASPNETDB so I can login to my site because I'm using authorization to this user ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using the Membership API.

If you are using ASP.NET on a machine with SQL Server Express Edition, the required by Membership API underlying data store is created automatically for you when you create the first user. This functionality is provided through the SqlMembershipProvider. The SqlMembershipProvider automatically creates a new database in the website’s App_Data special directory called ASPNETDB.MDB. This database implements the complete schema, which is necessary for storing and managing user information, role information, user-role assignments etc.

You can easily check it. In your web.config you should see something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

So this database should have been uploaded along with your web site.

Please consider this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) if you want to create aspnetdb or necessary tables in your own database (which is a good praxis).

May be you will be also interested in the similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743094/app-data-aspnetdb-mdf-to-sql-server-2005-or-08). Besides if you still want to get this .mdf database in SQL Server Management Studio you can learn how to attach a database [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Ok im gonna make a few assumptions here and explain them because this could be many things:

Assumption 1 (connection string issue). the user credentials for a database running on your local sql server are likely to be valid on the server on which you deploy to (seems to be the way of the world) try connecting to the remote database using the credentials in the remote "published" copy of the websites configuration file. (connection string)

Assumption 2 (publish settings not correct). when you use the "publish" option from within visual studio you only deploy the website to my knowledge but some say you can configure it to deploy the database as well.

I would suggest making a change (eg add a table to the aspnet database) on your dev machine then using publish to see if that new table appears on the remote server, if it doesn't go to the server explorer in visual studio and run the wizard by right clicking on your database and clicking on "publish to provider" i tend to push the entire db to a script file then manually run that on the remote database (seems the cleanest option).

Assumption 3 (does the database even exist on the server). I could be wrong here but from what you're saying it sounds like you published the application and not the database to the server ... that results in some nice yellow server errors.

Check that the database exists if not ... do as suggested in asumption 2 and push the database manually.